# Perform Lucene wildcard search

Tags: java, search, lucene

How does Lucene support wild card searches?

I want to search the words starting with ox 
I am searching the words with `ox*` but its also returning the unexpected results like `anti-oxide` - but I don't want it as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Lucene [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F) your query `ox*` should only match terms that begin with ox.

Because the `StandardTokenizer` considers [hyphen as a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832934/lucene-standard-analyzer-hyphen-consideration?rq=1), a word like `anti-oxide` is split into two words - `anti` and `oxide` and hence the match `anti-oxide` when you search for `ox*`.

You have 2 options to change this behavior:

1. Override the default Tokenizer and write your own to suit your needs
2. Ugly pre-processing of your text to replace/remove such delimiters. This may not be an ideal solution

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how your data is analyzed.  The StandardAnalyzer will separate terms on spaces and punctuation (among [many other rules](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/)).  Standard Analyzer is usually well suited to full text.  If it doesn't suit your particular needs, [many other analyzers](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/) are available.  Without more information on what you intend to accomplish, I can't really recommend a particular one.